# Execute 2 Query via PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file with the next code:

```
// UPDATE Gestion Password --> update usuarios set usuarios.USU_ClaveUsuario='$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_GESTION' where usuarios.USU_idUsuarios='$idusuario'
// UPDATE Moodle Password -->  update mdl_user set mdl_user.password='$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_MOODLE' where mdl_user.username='$idusuario'

if ($link->query($query) === TRUE) {
echo "Contra Cambiada";
} else {
echo "Contra NO cambiada"
};
```

Update gestion change password from one table,
and update moodle from other table.

I variables like ***$idusuario***, ***$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_GESTION*** and ***$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_MOODLE*** are taked from form I created on other page.

If make Query command from $query variable and if it done, show message "Contra Cambiada", else, "Contra No cambiada".

I want execute that 2 commands (are in //) in the same PHP File.

How I can do that?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a detailed explanation:

```
// UPDATE Gestion Password 
$updateUsearios  = "UPDATE usuarios SET usuarios.USU_ClaveUsuario = '$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_GESTION' WHERE usuarios.USU_idUsuarios='$idusuario'";

// If the update succeeded proceed to update the Moodle Password
if ($link->query($updateUsearios) === TRUE) {

    // Update Moodle Password
    $updateMdlUser = "UPDATE mdl_user SET mdl_user.password='$contrasenyaNuevaEncript_MOODLE' WHERE mdl_user.username='$idusuario'";

        // If the update suceeded return Contra Cambiada
        if ($link->query($updateMdlUser) === TRUE) {
            echo "Contra Cambiada";
        } 

        // In case of error return Contra No cambiada, indicate that the Moodle Password update failed and print the error
        else {
            echo "Contra NO cambiada. Moodle Update Password failed: " . $conn->error;
        }
} 
// In case of error return Contra No cambiada, indicate that the Gestion Password failed and print the error
else {
    echo "Contra NO cambiada. Update Gestion Password failed: " . $conn->error;
}
```